# how to push an element to an observable and update UI

Tags: angular, angular-observable, async-pipe

Can someone help me out with this?
I'm starting to learn about observables and async pipes in angular8.

I'm trying to add an element to my observable and also update my UI.
At this moment i have this, it adds my element in the beginning and at the end of my array.
What am i doing wrong?

in my component:

```js
    var comment = new Comment();
    this.postService.addComment(commentdto).subscribe((c) => {
      comment = c;
      this.post.subscribe(x => {
        x.comments.push(comment);
        this.post = of(x);
      });
    });
```

```html
<div *ngIf="post | async as p">
  <div class="post-container border-bottom border-dark mb-2">
    <h3 class="col-sm-12">{{p.text}}</h3>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <img class="img-fluid image-height" src="https://localhost:5003/posts/{{p.imageUrl}}" />
      <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 2%">
        <a style="margin-right:15px" class="pointer" (click)="vote(true, post)"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i> {{p.upVotes}}</a>
        <a style="margin-right:15px" class="pointer" (click)="vote(false, post)"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i> {{p.downVotes}}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h5>Comments:</h5>
  <div class="form-group mb-3">
    <textarea [(ngModel)]="addComment" class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea" placeholder="Add comment..."></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ml-auto" (click)="addCommentToPost()">Post</button>
  </div>
  <div *ngFor="let c of p.comments" class="container">
    <div class="row comment-bubble">
      {{c.text}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

service:

```js
addComment(comment: EditComment): Observable<Comment> {
    return this.http.post<Comment>(`${this.baseUrl}/AddComment`, comment, this.httpOptionsAuthentication)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  handleError(error) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // client-side error
      errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
    } else {
      // server-side error
      errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }
    console.log(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
```

Comment: Is your post variable an observable? I dont see why you need an observable inside another. Just  x.comments.push(c) inside the first observable should be enough. I assume you need to loop through x instead of p in the html part.

Comment: yes, it's an observable

Comment: It doesnt need to be. Post service is adding the comment, it is already an http observable. Unless you use facade partern, there is no reason to add observable inside observable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new observable. You have to emit a new value.

Without seeing the rest of your code, something like:

```js
post: Post; // I am assuming you have a type for a post.
post$ = new Subject<Post>(); // Our observable.
...
this.postService.addComment(commentdto).subscribe((comment) => {
  this.post.comments.push(comment);
  this.post$.next(this.post); // Emit a new value.
});
```

But this is a bit silly, having both a variable and an observable. It is probably better to not use AsyncPipe in this case.

```js
post: Post;
...
this.postService.addComment(commentdto).subscribe((comment) => {
  this.post.comments.push(comment);
});
```

```html
<div *ngIf="post">
  <div class="post-container border-bottom border-dark mb-2">
    <h3 class="col-sm-12">{{post.text}}</h3>
```

Comment: post variable is an observable.

Comment: Yes, but it shouldn't be an observable. But without posting the relevant code in your question or, even better, a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is difficult to provide a solution for your specific use-case.